# Let ImageView follow ListView scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

For an App I'm developing, I have an ImageView on Top of a ListView in a RelativeLayout. What I want is for the ImageView to scroll with the ListView. So if the ListView items move up, the ImageView should move up just as much. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: add your image view as a header to listview

Answer (score 2):

for that you should set header to listview

```
mListView.addHeaderView(mImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your imageview as a header to listview.

```
  listview.addHeaderView(ImageView);
```

The image will scroll along with listview.

public void addHeaderView (View v)

> Added in API level 1 Add a fixed view to appear at the top of the
>   list. If addHeaderView is called more than once, the views will appear
>   in the order they were added. Views added using this call can take
>   focus if they want.
>
> NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so ListView can
>   wrap the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header
>   and footer views.
>
> Parameters v  The view to add.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna go for adding Header, go for this:

```
listViewObj.addHeaderView(imgViewobj);
```

PS: use before `listViewObj.setAdapter();`

else take a look at this open source project, hope this would help:

[Link to  emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)